# measure theory problem and epsilon

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,S,\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $\epsilon>0$. Show that there exists $E\in S$ such that $\mu(E)<\infty$ and $\int f \leq \int_{E}f d\mu +\epsilon$. Where $f\in M(X,S,\mu)$ is positive.

My idea consisted of doing:

Let $\epsilon>0$. As $\int f d\mu-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound, there exists a simple function $\phi$ such that $0\leq \phi \leq f$ such that $\int f d\mu -\epsilon <\int \phi d\mu \leq \int f d\mu$.

Now, $\phi=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\mu(E_i)$, the standard representation. However, I am unsure as to how to construct a set $E$.

Comment: Is $M$ just the measurable functions? If so then I have a counterexample to your statement: let $X=[1,\infty)$ and equip it with the Lebesgue measure then consider $f(x)=1/x$. Then $\int_E f(x) dx \leq \int_{1}^{m(E)-1} 1/x dx = \ln(m(E)-1)$ but of course $\int_X f(x) dx = +\infty$.

Comment: If instead you assume integrability then turning the crank with simple functions will do what you want.

Comment: @Ian $f$ is positive and yes, it is measurable. I will edit now

Comment: @Ian When I equip the integral with the lebesgue measure, do I just get the Riemann integral?

Comment: Essentially it is like the improper Riemann integral with fewer regularity requirements and more absolute convergence requirement. But it agrees with all proper Riemann integrals.